# How to get inner array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get all the contents from an array.
This is the function that extracts the data for display via `innerHTML`:

```
window.location.href = 'gonative://contacts/getAll?callback=contacts_callback';

function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts.map(({givenName}) => givenName) + " " + 
                      obj.contacts.map(({familyName}) => familyName) + " " + " (" + 
                      obj.contacts.map(({organizationName}) => organizationName) + ") " + 
                      obj.contacts.map(({phoneNumbers.phoneNumber}) => phoneNumbers.phoneNumber) + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}
```

This is an example of what the input looks like when there are only 2 contacts:

```
{"success":true,"contacts":[
        {
            "emailAddresses":[],
            "phoneNumbers":
                [
                    {
                        "label":"unknown",
                        "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"
                    }
                ],
            "givenName":"John",
            "organizationName":"Apple",
            "familyName":"Appleseed",
        },
        {
            "emailAddresses":[],
            "phoneNumbers":
                [
                    {
                        "label":"unknown",
                        "phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"
                    }
                ],
            "givenName":"John",
            "organizationName":"Apple",
            "familyName":"Appleseed",
        },
    ]
}
```

I just want the result to be listed as:

> John Appleseed (Apple) XXX-XXXXXXX
>   John Appleseed (Apple) XXX-XXXXXXX

Comment: `phoneNumbers` is an array. Can a person have more than one in that array? What should happen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You are displaying all given names, then all family names, ...etc, each with a separate `.map()` call. Instead only perform one `.map()` call on the array and then display the properties for each iterated object.
- `phoneNumbers.phoneNumber` is not a correct reference. `phoneNumbers` is an array, so you should iterate it.

Also:

- Template literals make it maybe a bit easier to build the string
- You can use `.join("<br>")` to glue the lines together with line breaks.

Here is a corrected version:

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts.map(o => 
        `${o.givenName} ${o.familyName} (${o.organizationName}) ${
             o.phoneNumbers.map(n => n.phoneNumber)
        }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = {"success":true,"contacts":[{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"John","organizationName":"Apple","familyName":"Appleseed",},{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"John","organizationName":"Apple","familyName":"Appleseed",},]};

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an answer since is hard to tell what you can have in your `phoneNumbers` array and if you will also display one line for each phone number in that array.

I'll do something like this:

```
function contacts_callback(obj) {
  let arrayContacts = [];

  // Iterate over all your contacts
  obj.contacts.forEach(item => {
    // Iterate over each contact's phone numbers
    item.phoneNumbers.forEach(phone => {
      // Building your string with string interpolation and pushing to result array
      // You could also add <br> or other tags needed here
      arrayContacts.push(`${item.givenName} ${item.familyName} (${item.organizationName}) ${phone.phoneNumber}`);
    });    
  });
  // Return your array, use it in your innerHTNL, etc.
  return arrayContacts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your obj is called "obj", than:

```
const result = obj.contacts.map(contact =>{
    return `${contact.givenName} ${contact.familyName} (${contact.organizationName}) ${contact.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber}`
}
```

this code will give back an array of informations that U asked, but if user has more than 1 phone number, it will take only first from the list